# What's wrong with this defined function?

Tags: sml

Any one can help on this?
it posts an error

```
fun hypoexpo(l1:real,l2:real)=
let
val u1=uniform(0.0,1.0)
val u2=uniform(0.0,1.0)
val l=l1/(l2-l1)
if u1<0.5 then val h=~ln u2/l1
else val h=~ln u2/l2
in
h
end;
```

Comment: Please review [ask]. Be sure to also create an [mcve]. Do not use screenshots where you can just as easily copy/paste code/text into the question. Finally include any errors as well as the expected/actual behavior, do not make us guess what is transpiring on your PC

Comment: Can you add **more** details to your post instead of only posting a picture?

Comment: Just done......

Comment: Code inserted guys! Anyone can help..

Answer (score 2):

Between `let` and `in` only declarations can appear. The `if` construct is not part of the declaration syntax, it is an expression. You can simply change your code to the following:

```
fun hypoexpo(l1 : real, l2 : real) =
    let
      val u1 = uniform(0.0, 1.0)
      val u2 = uniform(0.0, 1.0)
      val l = l1/(l2-l1)
    in
      if u1 < 0.5 then ~ln u2/l1 else ~ln u2/l2
    end
```

You can also factor out the constant parts from the conditional, changing the last line to

```
~ln u2 / (if u1 < 0.5 then l1 else l2)
```

Either way, `l` seems to be unused.